# VBoxManage.exe startvm Could not find a registered machine named

Tags: windows, cygwin, virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox image called "mongo".

When I start windows and try to start the VM from cygwin, VBoxManage says that it cannot find teh machine:

`/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe startvm mongo --type headless
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'mongo'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(pszVM).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 575 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp`

It works from cmd **and** it works once I've started the VirtualBox.exe GUI, but not from cygwin, when the gui is not running:

Output from cmd:
`"\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" startvm mongo --type headless
Waiting for VM "mongo" to power on...
VM "mongo" has been successfully started.`

Output from cygwin when the GUI is running:
`/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe startvm mongo --type headless
Waiting for VM "mongo" to power on...
VM "mongo" has been successfully started.`

I'm using VirtualBox 4.3.18 on Windows 7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple workaround/solution?: I've linked the "VirtualBox VMs" folder from the Windows user's home dir into the user's home dir in cygwin.

```
ln -s /cygdrive/c/Users/<username>/VirtualBox\ VMs/ ~/
```

--> VMs are shared between cygwin, cmd and GUI.